# Combining three similar sql queries into a single result

Tags: sql, join, union

I have a table say (TimeValue) something like this

```
 Time    Value   Owner
 ======================
 1      10       A
 2      20       B
 3      30       C
 4      40       A
 5      50       B
 6      60       C
 7      70       A
 8      80       B
```

Now I have three sql statement like the followings

1. `select owner, value as 'First sql' from TimeValue where time >= 1 and time <= 3 group by owner`
2. `select owner, value as 'Second sql' from TimeValue where time >= 4 and time <= 6 group by owner`
3. `select owner, value as 'Third sql' from TimeValue where time >= 7 and time <= 9 group by owner`

Now these are the result of the above sql

1.

```
Value   Owner
=================
10       A
20       B
30       C
```

2.

```
Value   Owner
=================
40       A
50       B
60       C
```

3

```
Value   Owner
===============
70       A
80       B
90       C
```

My question, what would be the sql statement if I want the following result??

```
 Owner    First SQL     Second SQL     Third SQL
==================================================
  A        10            40              70
  B        20            50              80
  C        30            60              90
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a `CASE` statement, like this:

```
SELECT
    owner
,   MAX(CASE WHEN time >= 1 AND time <= 3 THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS FIRST
,   MAX(CASE WHEN time >= 4 AND time <= 6 THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS SECOND
,   MAX(CASE WHEN time >= 7 AND time <= 9 THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS THIRD
FROM TimeValue
GROUP BY owner
```

Note that you need an aggregating function, such as `MAX`, around `value`. In fact, many RDBMS engines would not even take SQL without an aggregating function around it.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4970cb/4)

```
select owner, 
SUM(case when (time >= 1 and time <= 3) then value end) as 'FirstSQL',
SUM(case when (time >= 4 and time <= 6) then value end) as 'SecondSQL',
SUM(case when (time >= 7 and time <= 9) then value end) as 'ThirdSQL'
from TimeValue 
group by owner
```

base on your example you should use SUM instead of MAX

Answer (score 0):

The same idea with dasblinkenlight but different approach and I agree on  aggregating function, such as MAX or SUM

```
SELECT
    owner,
MAX(IF(time between 1 and 3, value,NULL) ) as first,
MAX(IF(time between 4 and 6, value,NULL) ) as sec,
MAX(IF(time between 7 and 9, value,NULL) ) as third

FROM TimeValue 
GROUP BY owner
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use self-joins:

```
select
  tv0.owner
, tv0.value sql1
, tv1.value sql2
, tv2.value sql3

from timevalue tv0
inner join timevalue tv1 on tv1.owner = tv0.owner
inner join timevalue tv2 on tv2.owner = tv0.owner

where tv0.time between 1 and 3
and tv1.time between 4 and 6
and tv2.time between 7 and 9
```